# Neo4j Desktop in a disconnected environment takes a lot of time to start?

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-desktop

I installed Neo4j Desktop client on disconnected windows environment (no internet),when starting the programmer it takes a lot of time (more then 30m) to get ready ,actually it get stacked on the " Preparing application " step :

[image]

I'm looking for any way to tell Neo4j to skip checking for updates ?

The installation is on aws Appstream Stacks ,the stack has connection to my VPC  but  not to the internet :
[image]

This is a part of the log where it get stack requesting for a specific [Url](https://dist.neo4j.org/neo4j-desktop/win/latest.yml) :

[log file](https://file.io/gQSh0xot8vjh)

Comment: Was the Neo4j Desktop already installed on this computer? Usually it can take a long time if it needs to check existing databases in the system, but not 30 minutes

Comment: actuality this is an aws Appstream Stacks so every time i connect it create a new session ,but even thou as you said 30 is a lot of time!!  because i tray to simulate the same environment in my local desktop with no internet connection and it takes only 10m to start !

Comment: also as u see in the log file it keep attempting to check for that link to see if there is internet or no

Comment: Yes, but checking for new version shouldn't be blocking as you noticed it works eventually

Comment: @TomažBratanič did you ever tried to install it in a semi disconnected environment ?  in my case i did the installation in AWS Appstream Stacks so it has connection to the VPC but no internet .

Comment: i updated my question ,you can see more logs